# Why removeAttr('placeholder') jquery function is not removing :placeholder-shown pseudo class from input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i try to remove placeholder attribute from an input element using removeAttr('placeholder') :placeholder-shown pseudo class is not getting removed from and element, instead it changes the color of input value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.input-field').removeAttr('placeholder');
});
```

```css
.input-field:placeholder-shown {
  color: #cacaca;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="my placeholder">
```

[Code example](https://jsfiddle.net/francisstalin/zsnwnoqj/)

Comment: I agree that it does appear to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/k8997bLp/

Comment: @adeneo : pls check my fiddle url

Comment: @RobM. - actually it doesn't, the color does change, it seems like a bug in Chrome, because it shouldn't

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ez9zaswq/1/ works fine check the fiddle.

Comment: @adeneo that's just because there is no default color set for that element, if you add a color for the element then it doesn't set and stay that way https://jsfiddle.net/k8997bLp/1/

Comment: Works for me (Chrome 48, Yosemite)

Comment: @ameenuall0007 : type and see the text, still text color has placeholder color

Comment: @RobM. - sure, but if you remove the style for `:placeholder-shown` it doesn't change the color, and that pseudo-class is not supposed to target the inputted text when the element isn't showing a placeholder

Comment: It can also be fixed by just setting the attribute to a space -> `$('.input-field').attr('placeholder', ' ');`

Comment: @adeneo : giving empty string will work .I would like to know why it is not getting removed. Is it jquery issue or browser issue.

Comment: In my chrome (48 on El Capitan) I have to add a vendor prefix for it to work: https://jsfiddle.net/k8997bLp/2/

Comment: @RobM. - that's strange, Chrome 48 on Ubuntu changes the text color to the same grey as the placeholder would normally have, even when you type into the input, but that's only if the placeholder was removed or is empty, if there is a placeholder, even an string containing just a space, it works as expected.

Comment: @RobM : how to support other browsers

Comment: @FrancisStalin - You realize Webkit/Blink browsers are about the only browsers that supports this -> http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder-shown

Comment: This is where I found the vendor specific selectors: http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/placeholder-pseudo-class/

Comment: Your fiddle works fine in W7 with: chrome, Opera, FF, IE11 and the last safari avalaible for windows

Comment: @adeneo : the list which you have mentioned has chrome 48 support,still why i am facing the issue

Comment: @GCyrillus : Can you enter some value and see the text color, you can see it will be place holder color.

Comment: @FrancisStalin https://jsfiddle.net/zsnwnoqj/1/ it's a matter of correct or not syntax ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus you have used .input-field::placeholder-show , pls see the updated one https://jsfiddle.net/zsnwnoqj/1/ . Entered text is red color.

Comment: @FrancisStalin arf, feel stupid here , did not even noticed this. Never mind my comments here

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, this should be your solution to support all browsers:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.input-field').removeAttr('placeholder').removeClass('input-field');
});
```

Where .input-field contains your reference to your color.

```
.input-field::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: If I use browser specific ::-webkit-input-placeholder pseudo class it is working fine. :placeholder-shown  psesudo class is not working even though it has chrome support.

Comment: How does `removeClass` with the `document` as an argument do anything ?

Answer (score 0):

This css solved my issue.

```css
.input-field {
  color: #000;
}
:placeholder-shown,
::-webkit-input-placeholder,
::-moz-placeholder,
:-ms-input-placeholder {
 color: #cacaca;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/francisstalin/k8997bLp/3/

Comment: That works. Perhaps you should associate that placeholder with a specific class, so you don't have all placeholders acting the same way. Since you were already using jquery to remove the placeholder attr, it felt elegant enough to also use removeClass as well (since you're already operating on the element).